# How do delete a specific module using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have two modules with 30+ resources in each. I want to destroy all the resources in one particular region and nothing in the other region. How to destroy the complete module instead of destroying each resource individually using terraform.

```
module "mumbai" {
  source                    = "./site-to-site-vpn-setup"
  providers                 = { aws = aws.mumbai }
}

module "seoul" {
  source                    = "./site-to-site-vpn-setup"
  providers                 = { aws = aws.seoul }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just either remove the relevant module (or comment out), then run terraform plan/apply? Because Terraform is infrastructure-as-code, when you change anything in the code, it will reflect those changes in your infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the target when running `terraform destroy`.

For example, if you want to delete only the Mumbai module:

```
terraform destroy -target module.mumbai
```